# display the labels in doughnut chart

Tags: angular

I am using Angular ng2-charts to dispay data in the doughnut chart, Its all working fine in local version, the problem is when i push the project in dev version, labels on doughnut chart disappeared. I don't find where is the issue.
[image: the doughnut chart in Local version]
[image: the doughnut chart in Dev version]

and this the Code

```
  public doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'];
  public doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet;
  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
  public colors: any[] = [{ backgroundColor: ["#E3F0FD", "#C4F8DD", "#A499FF"] }];
  public chartOptions: any = {
  legend: {
    display: false,
   },
  pieceLabel: {
   render: function (args) {
    const label = args.label,
      value = args.value;
      return value +"%";
  },
  fontStyle: 'bold',
}
}
```

then i call the doughnutChartData in ngAfterViewInit that way

```
        this.doughnutChartData = [[Test1.data,Test2.data,Test3.data]]
```

And in HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" #myChart baseChart [data]="doughnutChartData" [options]="chartOptions"
                    height="70" width="100" [colors]="colors" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                    [chartType]="doughnutChartType">
                </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the plugin [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-datalabels). From the [example](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/PieChart):

```
import * as pluginDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

...

public pieChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];

public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
  ...,
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      formatter: (value, ctx) => {
        const label = ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
        return label;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And in your template:

```
<canvas ...
  [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
</canvas>
```

The plugin requires Chart.js 3.x.